# Yarn deploy error: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yarn-lock.json

I am trying to deploy the React application but facing the following error:

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:806:20)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:677:19)
    at ChildProcessWorker.send (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:291:17)
    at WorkerPool.send (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\WorkerPool.js:32:34)
    at Farm._process (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:129:10)
    at Farm._enqueue (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:152:10)
    at Farm._push (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:159:12)
    at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:90:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Farm.doWork (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:56:12)
    at JestWorker._callFunctionWithArgs (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\jest-worker\build\index.js:143:23)
    at TaskRunner.runTask (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:41:26)
    at enqueue (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:89:35)
    at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\packs_frontend\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js:113:86
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at internal/child_process.js:810:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  errno: 'UNKNOWN',
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'write'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have tried cleaning the cache and increasing the memory by the following commands:

```
yarn cache clean
```

and inside `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired --max-old-space-size=8192 build",
    "postbuild": "node deploycopy.js",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

But the problem still persists

Tried adding the following in environment variables:

```
C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

C:\Program Files\nodejs; C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

But no use

[image]

Comment: try to delete `data = {}` and check if the error disappear. Because, normally data is an instance of request.

Comment: Which node version do you use ?

Comment: @Nezih v12.16.3

Comment: is the error occuring when "yarn build"

Comment: @NewGuy9000 the error occurs when i try `yarn deploy`

Comment: did you use ```yarn create react-app myApp```